# Can we calculate the sum of numbers which will be created through different numbers by using combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics

Using the digits $1,2,3,4$ (without repetition) how many numbers can be created and what will be the sum of them?
I figured out that $4!$ or $24$ numbers can be created.But i can't figure out the sum.
Could you please solve this?

Comment: In finding the sum, recognize that $1$ will occur as the ones digit exactly $\frac{1}{4}$ of the time, and so will $2$ occur as the ones digit exactly $\frac{1}{4}$ of the time, etc...  Further $1$ will occur as the tens digit exactly $\frac{1}{4}$ of the time, and so on...  Can you continue from here?

Comment: If that hint doesn't make sense for you, you can try doing it with 1,2,3 instead of 1,2,3,4.  There are only six numbers to add, but it should be enough for you to notice what the pattern is.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use all the numbers then 24 is the correct answer. The sum should be 66660. The following code in Mathematica gives the answer: Total[FromDigits /@ Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4}]].

Also, here is the list of numbers: {1234, 1243, 1324, 1342, 1423, 1432, 2134, 2143, 2314, 2341, 2413, 2431, 3124, 3142, 3214, 3241, 3412, 3421, 4123, 4132, 4213, 4231, 
4312, 4321}.

In each of the thousands, hundreds, tens and ones positions you will have six of each of the numbers 1,2,3,4. Since 6(1 + 2 + 3 + 4) = 60, this means that from the thousands position you get 60000, from the hundreds position you get 6000, from the tens position you get 600 and from the ones you get 60.